# Question on discrepancy between Rambam and Gemara

Tags: rambam, chulin-tractate

If someone separated the first shearings of wool from his sheep to give to a Kohen, and he loses it, he is responsible to replace it ([Rambam, Bikkurim 10,8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_First_Fruits_and_other_Gifts_to_Priests_Outside_the_Sanctuary.10.8?lang=he)).  Doesn't that contradict the Gemara in Hullin ([130b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.130b.6?lang=he)) that someone who damages or eats gifts for the Kohen is exempt from paying because it's money that no one can demand?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a moment to look over our [tour] where you’ll find useful information about our site. I’ve gone ahead and helped you out with the tags and replaced the more yeshivish terminology you used with wording that’s easier for the layman to understand. If you don’t like any of these changes or want to change more, please feel more than welcome to [edit] it yourself. Thank you for your insightful question and I hope to see you around!

Comment: Does the same not apply to Pidyon Haben?

Answer (score 4):

See Kessef Mishneh [ad loc.](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_First_Fruits_and_other_Gifts_to_Priests_Outside_the_Sanctuary.10.8.1?lang=he) who explains that this is a specific rule which applies to the first shearings (*reishit hagez*), derived from the word תתן used in [Devarim 18:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.18.4?lang=he&aliyot=0).